# What is the Levy measure of $\int_0^\cdot \int_{0<|x|\le r} x \tilde N(dx,dt) + \int_0^\cdot \int_{|x|>r} x N(dx,dt)$?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, levy-processes

> Let $N$ be a Poisson random measure on $(\mathbf R^d\setminus\{0\})\times \mathbf R_+$ with intensity measure $\nu\otimes dt$. Here $dt$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbf R_+$. Let $\tilde N$ be the associated compensated Poisson random measure. Namely, $\tilde N(A\times [0,t]) = N(A\times [0,t]) - t\nu(A)$ for $A\in\mathcal B(\mathbf R^d\setminus\{0\})$ and $t>0$. Given a constant $r>1$, we consider the following pure jump Levy process
>   \begin{equation}\tag{1}
> L_t = \int_0^t \int_{0<|x|\le r} x \tilde N(dx,dt) + \int_0^t \int_{|x|>r} x N(dx,dt).
> \end{equation}

Now there are two ways to identify the Levy triplet of $L=\{L_t\}_{t\ge0}$ associated to the indicate function $\mathbf 1_{\{0<|x|\le 1\}}$. But what I am confused is I get two different results!

---

**Solution 1.** Rewrite (1) to
\begin{equation}
L_t = \int_0^t \int_{0<|x|\le 1} x \tilde N(dx,dt) + \int_0^t \int_{|x|>1} x N(dx,dt) - t \int_{1<|x|\le r} x\nu(dx).
\end{equation}
Hence, the Levy triplet of $L$ associated to $\mathbf 1_{\{0<|x|\le 1\}}$ is
\begin{equation}
\left( - \int_{1<|x|\le r} x\nu(dx), 0, \nu\right).
\end{equation}

---

**Solution 1.** Define a new Poisson random measure $M$ by $M(A\times [0,t]) = rN(rA\times [0,t])$, where $rA:=\{rx: x\in A\}$. Then $M$ has intensity $\mu(A) = r\nu(rA)$ and associated compensated Poisson random measure $\tilde M(A\times [0,t]) = r\tilde N(rA\times [0,t])$. Use the change of variable $x = ry$ to rewrite (1) to
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
L_t &= \int_0^t \int_{0<|y|\le 1} ry \tilde N(rdy,dt) + \int_0^t \int_{|y|>1} ry N(rdy,dt) \\
&= \int_0^t \int_{0<|y|\le 1} y \tilde M(dy,dt) + \int_0^t \int_{|y|>1} y M(dy,dt).
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Hence, the Levy triplet of $L$ associated to $\mathbf 1_{\{0<|x|\le 1\}}$ is
\begin{equation}
( 0, 0, r\nu(r\cdot)).
\end{equation}

---

I cannot find anything wrong in the two solutions. But the results are contradictory, there must be somewhere going wrong. I am confused then... Any hints or comments will be appreciated. TIA...

---

**EDIT:** Assume $r$ is an integer so that the new measure $M$ is exactly integer-valued and hence a Poisson random measure?

Comment: Ok... I know where the mistake is. The new random measure $M$ is not a Poisson random measure even though $r$ is integer, because the process $\{M(A\times[0,t])\}_{t\ge0}$ has jumps larger than 1...